# Return specific values in TextView using onclick

Tags: android, onclick, textview

Is this java class using onclick method is correct to return the value as "1" in the display screen on the user click. which in this case display is txtscreen. Being novice in this part. I need help to make sure it will work.

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Strnum1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

View rootview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOne);

    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnsin:
            ((TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.txtScreen)).setText("1");
            break;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this line

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScreen)).setText("1");
```

instead of

```
((TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.txtScreen)).setText("1");
```